# How to run nutch 1.9 in eclipse on windows?

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, nutch

I want to run Nutch 1.9 in Eclipse on Windows. I followed the tutorial from http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/RunNutchInEclipse and opened the project in Eclipse.

But when I run Nutch, I get the following error:

```
2014-09-19 17:45:48,039 INFO  crawl.Injector (Injector.java:inject(283)) - Injector: starting at 2014-09-19 17:45:48
2014-09-19 17:45:48,043 INFO  crawl.Injector (Injector.java:inject(284)) - Injector: crawlDb: K:/kumar/Nutch/apache-nutch-1.9/crawlresult
2014-09-19 17:45:48,043 INFO  crawl.Injector (Injector.java:inject(285)) - Injector: urlDir: K:/kumar/Nutch/apache-nutch-1.9/urls
2014-09-19 17:45:48,043 INFO  crawl.Injector (Injector.java:inject(294)) - Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
2014-09-19 17:45:48,207 INFO  jvm.JvmMetrics (JvmMetrics.java:init(71)) - Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
2014-09-19 17:45:48,252 WARN  mapred.JobClient (JobClient.java:configureCommandLineOptions(661)) - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
2014-09-19 17:45:48,268 INFO  mapred.FileInputFormat (FileInputFormat.java:listStatus(192)) - Total input paths to process : 1
2014-09-19 17:45:48,485 INFO  mapred.JobClient (JobClient.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1275)) - Running job: job_local_0001
2014-09-19 17:45:48,487 INFO  mapred.FileInputFormat (FileInputFormat.java:listStatus(192)) - Total input paths to process : 1
2014-09-19 17:45:48,526 INFO  mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:runOldMapper(347)) - numReduceTasks: 0
2014-09-19 17:45:48,565 INFO  plugin.PluginRepository (PluginManifestParser.java:parsePluginFolder(87)) - Plugins: looking in: K:\Nutch\apache-nutch-1.9\plugins
2014-09-19 17:45:48,566 WARN  plugin.PluginRepository (PluginManifestParser.java:parsePluginFolder(101)) - java.io.FileNotFoundException: K:\Nutch\apache-nutch-1.9\plugins\creativecommons\plugin.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

It seems that Hadoop is the causing error. I don't know how to solve this problem. I know Nutch requires Unix environment. But, I want to run Nutch in Eclipse on Windows.

Can anybody help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Download cygwin, then add that to your path of the environment variables. I think your problem is caused by the fact that windows can't invoke a unix native command. That is what I did however as soon as i got past that problem, I encountered other problems.